# Tuning background subtraction with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video

My question is the final paragraph.

I am trying to use one of OpenCV's background subtractors as a means of detecting human hands. The code that tries to do this is as follows:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG2 = cv::createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
cv::Mat fgMaskMOG2;
pMOG2->apply(input, fgMaskMOG2, -1);
cv::namedWindow("FG Mask MOG 2");
cv::imshow("FG Mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);
```

When I initially ran the program on my own test video I was greeted with this (ignore the name of the right most window):
[image: The left image is the mask calculated by the MOG2 algorithm]
As you can see a mask is not detected for my moving hand at all, given that the background in my video is completely stationary (there were maybe one or two white pixels at a time showing up in the mask). So I tried using a different video, one that many examples seemed to use which was moving traffic.
[image: Attempt at traffic background subtraction]

You can see it picked up on a moving car -very- slightly. I have tried (for both these videos) setting the "learning threshold" for the `apply` method to many values between 0 and 1 and there was not much variation at all from the results you can see above.

Have I missed anything with regards to setting up the background subtraction or are the videos particularly hard examples to deal with? Where can I adjust the settings of the background subtraction to favour my setup (if anywhere)? I will repeat the fact that in both videos the camera is stationary.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in python but convert and try it. Approve if it works.

```
   if (cap.isOpened() == False):
        print("Error opening video stream or file")
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
    min_thresh=800
    max_thresh=10000
    fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
    connectivity = 4
    # Read until video is completed
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            print("Frame detected")
            frame1 = frame.copy()  
            fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame1)

            fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
            output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(
                fgmask, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
            for i in range(output[0]):
                if output[2][i][4] >= min_thresh and output[2][i][4] <= max_thresh:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (output[2][i][0], output[2][i][1]), (
                        output[2][i][0] + output[2][i][2], output[2][i][1] + output[2][i][3]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow('detection', frame)
            cv2.imshow('detection', fgmask)
```

Update cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2 by changing history, varThreshold, and detectShadows=True. You can also change kernel sizel, remove noise etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try using MOG subtractor instead of MOG2 background subtractor.. It might help you.

Because most times MOG subtractor would be handy. But the worst thing is MOG subtractor has been moved to bgsegm package. It's a contrib package. It is available in OpenCv git hub page itself.

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: As much as I would like to just get this working, this doesn't answer my question(s). Additionally from looking at resources such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-L9FoH3D9w) MOG2 is supposed to be very good: